# Powershell how to pass System variables

Tags: powershell, escaping, special-characters, powershell-3.0

I am trying to execute the below command on powershell, but the encryption password is not recognised.
This password is used in integration tests.

```
gradle publish -Djasypt.encrypt.password = $xyz!@
```

The below command also does not work

```
cmd /c gradle publish -Djasypt.encrypt.password = $xyz!@
```

The same command works well on CMD

Any suggestions on passing the arguments (with `-D`)?

Comment: Try giving the password in encoded form, eg. ! will encode to %21, and similarly other special symbols

Comment: Is the password contained within the variable `$xyz`? Because you are passing in the contents of that variable (empty if it does not exist) and you would need to escape the `$` with a backtick if not.

Answer (score 1):

`$` is the [sigil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigil_(computer_programming)) denoting a variable in PowerShell just like most other shells, so `$xyz` means the variable named xyz. You need to [escape](https://serverfault.com/q/47811/343888) that [symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-7.1) with a backtick

```powershell
gradle publish -Djasypt.encrypt.password = `$xyz!@
```

Alternatively just [quote the string with a single quote](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1) to prevent variable substitution

```powershell
gradle publish -Djasypt.encrypt.password = '$xyz!@'
```

Comment: Thank you .-Djasypt.encrypt.password = `$xyz!@ worked well

Comment: @amuru please don't write [thank you comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269681/995714). Instead just click the green checkmark to mark the question as solved. See also the 1-minute [tour] to understand how this site works

Comment: [What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/230282)